# Overflow:hidden к тегу HTML и почему скролл эффекты пропали Js не работает

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет. В своем сайте я хочу поставить скролл не с самого начала страницы, а после шапки чтобы начинался. Для этого я поставил к `<html>` `overflow:hidden` и создал новый блок `.scrolltaker` c `position:absolute`, в котором внутри будет `.wrapper` с `position:relative`. Шапка у меня не входит внутрь `.wrapper`-а, поэтому тут проблем нет. После создания этого тега и стилей все js эффекты, включая эффекты плагина skrollr, пропали. Когда я удаляю `overflow:hidden` с тега `<html>`, все работает отлично, а когда восстанавливаю, ничего не работает с анимацией. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой, пожалуйста, помогите.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $('.menu ').addClass("sticky");
    $('.blog').addClass("smaller");
    $('.fullName').addClass("smaller");
    $('.next').addClass("smaller");
    $('.surname').addClass("smaller");
    $('.menu_right').addClass("normalize");
  } 
  else {
    $('.menu').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.blog').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.fullName').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.next').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.surname').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.menu_right').removeClass("normalize");
  }
});
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
body {
    font-family: "RobotoRegular", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 100%; // заменил max-height: 5470px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;

}
.scrolltaker {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto; // заменил overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 0; // заменил height: 890px;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 970px;
    min-height: 5600px;
    // убрал height: auto!important;
    // убрал display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    // убрал overflow-y:hidden;
}
.menu {
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 background: #bdc3c7; 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #bdc3c7 , #2c3e50);
 background: linear-gradient(to left, #bdc3c7 , #2c3e50); 
}
.menu.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: 2;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.menu_li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px;
 color: white;
 line-height: 30px;
}
.fullName {
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.fullName.smaller {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 font-size: 15px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.blog {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
.blog.smaller {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 font-size: 15px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.surname {
 font-family: "ArialRoundedMTBold" ,sans-serif;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
.surname.smaller {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.next {
 font-size: 28px;
}
.next.smaller {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu_right {
 padding: 11px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 float: right;
 font-family: "ArialRoundedMTBold" ,sans-serif;
 color: white;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.menu_right.normalize {
 position: relative;
 line-height: 22px;
 top: -8px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.menu_right:hover {
 color: #2F4153;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrolltaker">
  <div class="wrapper">

  </div>
</div>
 <header class="header">
    <div class="menu">
     <ul>
      <a href="test.html"><li class="menu_li"><span class="surname">Вася </span><span class="next">notes</span></li></a>
      <li class="menu_li"><span class="blog"> Блог </span><span class="fullName">геннадия </span></li>
      <a href="index.html"><li class="menu_right">Обо мне</li></a>
      <li class="menu_right">Книги</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </header>
```

Из за плагина skrollr header находится снаружи wrapper-а.

Comment: Не понятна проблема с skrollr, но [взгляните](https://jsfiddle.net/x2nqdcfm/), может поможет.

Comment: @Dmitry проблема в том что при таком коде у меня js не работает.Покажите еще вариант пожалуйста с работа способным джаваскриптом .

Comment: [Добавьте свой код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) в текст вопроса.

Comment: @Dmitry я изменил вопрос посмотрите пожалуйста